# Invalid Argument fdopen with indirection

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have a small program that errors if I use indirection or not (in the shell)

```
FILE* f = fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "r+");
fprintf(f, "test\n");
fclose(f);
```

This line segfaults with an "Invalid Argument" when the following cmd is executed:

```
./test > output.txt
```

However, this does not error if I do the following (my program prints to stdout):

```
./test
```

Since I am getting an invalid argument, what about the indirection is causing fdopen to error? Do the read/write permissions of a stdout change when using indirection?

NOTE: The above behavior also occurs with this alternative way:

```
fprintf(stdout, "test\n");
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Yes, with output redirection the file is opened write-only, whereas when stdin/stdout/stderr are all the terminal, they're usually all read-write.  You should of course check the return value of `fdopen` to avoid the segfault.

Comment: Changing the mode didn't help. "w" or "w+" instead of "r+" still does not open the file. Of course, I can avoid the segfault, but my goal here is to be able to have the indirection actually work. Is it possible?

Comment: It works for me with `"w"`, are you sure your test is correct (and you saved the file and recompiled, etc)?  `"w+"` will of course fail for the same reason as `"r+"`.

Comment: thank you. looks like changing the w+ to w, i forgot to recompile. I can mark you as the answer for this question if you post an answer.